# Entity Framework Core LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm fairly new to EF Core, and I am trying to filter a set of jobs based on whether the appointment date is in the past and the status.

Why would this result in an error?

```
var maxJobAgeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);

JobSummaries.Where(j => DateTime.Parse(j.AppointmentDate) < maxJobAgeDate && j.JobStatus == JobStatus.CompleteSignOffConfirmed);
```

The error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(j => DateTime.Parse(j.AppointmentDate) < __maxJobAgeDate_0 && (int)j.JobStatus == 4)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I'm using EF Core.

Comment: It most probably is `DateTime.Parse` method. What is the format of the `AppointmentDate` string in `DateTime.Parse(j.AppointmentDate)`

Comment: @Zee "2022-03-01" etc

Comment: Why are you parsing a string into a DateTime _inside the query_? Why is a DateTime object stored in your database as a string?

Comment: Why is this a string field instead of `date`? That's a database bug. Fix it so you don't have to parse anything

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all. I have just started on the project and did not create the data structures or database. I will question why `AppointmentDate` is not a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the date format while converting in the Non-standard ISO types.

Try this.

```
JobSummaries.Where(j => DateTime.ParseExact(j.AppointmentDate,"yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < maxJobAgeDate 
                && j.JobStatus == JobStatus.CompleteSignOffConfirmed).ToList();
```

**I strongly recommend fixing this at a database level**

Comment: Same error: `The LINQ expression 'DbSet<JobSummary>.Where(j => DateTime.ParseExact(s: j.AppointmentDate, format: "yyyy-MM-dd", provider: __InvariantCulture_0) < __maxJobAgeDate_1 && (int)j.JobStatus == 4)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().`

Comment: I added a .ToList() at the end to force evaluation. Try it now